# VBA to paste data on the cells without changing format

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro-enabled protected workbook where the user is allowed to edit only a certain fields or rows(150 to 200) on all sheets.

The concern is I am not able to set the formatting on the editable fields, so when the user copy anything on the fields it takes the source format and it clutters the sheet.

I tried to use the following but that didn't help. Please suggest.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
Option Explicit 

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Row >= 150 And Target.Row <= 200 Then 

        Dim vNewValues as Variant
        NewValues = Target

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo

        Target = NewValues

        Application.EnableEvents = true

  End If

End Sub
```

It works by storing the new values (those copied or entered into the cells) into an array, then performing an undo, which will erase the operation (and any undesired formatting), then places only the values (from the stored array) into the range.

The `If` condition may need tweaking based on your actual requirements.

Comment: Apologize, I just noticed that row number varies from sheet to sheet. So, I am not sure if I can tweak the code to input all rows numbers. I would rather want to paste-values on all the rows which user is allowed to edit and on all sheets.

Comment: If all rows are locked and user cannot edit any undesired rows then the `IF` block can go away. Or, you can based on the sheet, by using say `Select Case` against `Sh.name`

Comment: It would not work if we remove if function, the screen would flash and input(pasted data) disappears from the field. I tried appending `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` but that dint help.

Comment: @sady - without knowing more about your specifics its hard to help. code works for me with or without `IF` block.

Comment: Just to isolate. I tried the above piece of code (without if) on a new blank workbook and issue remains same Input disappears. Let me be more clear, I would like to paste anything as plain text on fields that user can edit. No matter if he copies data in any other format while pasting it should use the destination formatting or paste it as plain text.

Comment: @sady - Sorry, there was a type here: `Target = NewValues`. (it previously said `NewValues`). Try again. Also notice, I added `Option Explicit` to the top of the code. This will ensure that variable names will always match before allowing you to run.

Answer (score 1):

```
Range.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks
```

Should just copy the values without copying the formatting from the initial range.

Comment: problem is no one can control how user will enter (copy / paste) data